# How to fix build erorrs?

Tags: kotlin, build, qr-code

I am new to Android Studio and I am trying to build a simple QR Code Scanner.  However, when I attempt the build I am presented with these errors:

```
 failed app/src/main/java/com/example/myapplication/MainActivity.kt
 Unresolved reference: new
 Unresolved reference: initiateScan
 Type mismatch: inferred type is Int but Intent! was expected
 Type mismatch: inferred type is Int but Intent? was expected
```

I am not really sure where to go from here in order to fix it.  Any help would be greatly apprecited!  Here is my code:

```
//package com.example.myapplication
package com.example.vicky.qrcodescanner


import android.R.attr
import android.app.Activity
import android.content.Intent
import android.os.Bundle
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import com.example.myapplication.R
import com.google.zxing.integration.android.IntentIntegrator
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*


class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    fun OnCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        btn_scan.setOnClickListener {
            new IntentIntegrator(this).initiateScan();
//            val scanner = IntentIntegrator(activity:this)
//
//            scanner.initiateScan()
        }
    }

    override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        if(resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            val result =
                IntentIntegrator.parseActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, attr.data)
            if (result != null) {
                if (result.contents == null) {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Cancelled", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Scanned: " + result.contents, Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .show()
                }
            } else {
                super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, attr.data)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
} else {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, attr.data)
}
```

to

```
} else {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
}
```

Comment: Thank you!  That takes care of this error:

    Type mismatch: inferred type is Int but Intent? was expected

But I am still left with these three:

    Unresolved reference: new
    Unresolved reference: initiateScan
    Type mismatch: inferred type is Int but Intent! was expected

I am assuming these other errors are the result of similar mistakes and will search for the appropriate documentation.